# ¿ Como contar los valores de un arreglo que sean iguales y poner el numero total de esos elementos iguales en un mensaje?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero que se muestre en mi mensaje ó en un icono de notfificación que estoy haciendo solo las notificaciones que tienen estado "1"

```
for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) { // total de los objetos del arreglo 
   if (data1[i].estado == "1") {  // todos los elementos que su estado sea igual a 1
    // Aqui esta mi duda.
   }
}
```

Comment: Deberías crear una variable de tipo array y _pushear_ cada elemento coincidente en éste

Comment: agrega el JSON de prueba y te muestro una forma muy elegante de hacerlo

Comment: (2) [{…}, {…}]0: {mensaje: "Su solicitud fúe aprobada", emisor: "Pigmetasa", estado: "1", fecha: "2018-08-17 17:12:37.063", tipomensaje: "1", …}1: {mensaje: "Solicitud de crédito ha sido creada con exito", emisor: "", estado: "0", fecha: "2018-08-21 17:24:33.613", tipomensaje: "1", …}length: 2__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: Quiero que se muestre en mi mensaje ó en un icono de notfificación que estoy haciendo solo las notificaciones que tienen estado "1"

Comment: Es decir, si vienen 4 notificaciones en el array y dos de esas 4 tienen estado 1, contarlas y mostrar el total solo de las que tienen estado 1.

Comment: puedes agregar el json de prueba en la respuesta, y borrar los comentarios , trata que sea bien un json de prueba

Answer (score 1):

Usando `filter()` es mas corto

```js
let arr = [1,2,1,3,45,6,7,8,9,1,3,2,1]

console.log(arr.filter(e=>e===1).length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Está solucionado. Habia de agregar un `counter` nada mas.

```
var counter=0;
counter++;
$("#id_de_tu_elemento").html(counter);
```

Comment: Por favor, recuerda [aceptar tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.